# reduce speed during animating a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am looking for a solution to animate a element from width 0 to width 100% using jquery animate(I think this is not the right solution for this). The bigger the element gets the slower should the animation go, so the speed of the animation should slow down more when the element gets bigger. There isn't much demo code to give you so I really hope that somebody does understand what I am trying to build.

// the code(not the best way to do something like this)

```
$('.element').animate({width: '20%'},2000,function(){
    $('.element').animate({width: '40%'},4000,function(){
        $('.element').animate({width: '60%'},8000,function(){
            $('.element').animate({width: '80%'},16000,function(){
                $('.element').animate({width: '100%'},32000,function(){

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Using easing does not do the trick!**

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var height = $('.element').height(),
    seconds = 1, 
    minRange = 500, 
    maxRange = 1500;
    time = height * seconds;

time = Math.min(time, maxRange);
time = Math.max(time, minRange);
$('.element').animate({width: '100%'},time);
```

Comment: Not working...dont know why you are using the elements height?

Comment: @user759235 http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/RZXbK/ , to calculate the content size I am calculating the height

Comment: Seen the demo, but I am not trying to slidedown something but to animate the width of an element(from 0% to 100%)

Answer (score 0):

you can try use linear

```
$('.element').animate({width: '100%'},1000 'linear')
```